# AttributeError: VerifiedHTTPSConnection instance has no attribute '_tunnel_host'

Tags: python, django, https, pip

When executing many commands eg. 
    `sudo pip install requests==1.2.3` 
the following error occurs
There seems to be an error with the connection

---

```
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Sun Jan  5 19:13:26 2014
Downloading/unpacking requests==1.2.3
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/tmp/pip_build_root...
Exception:
....
AttributeError: VerifiedHTTPSConnection instance has no attribute '_tunnel_host'
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [issue 485 of aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/485) where the same symptom is described. You should have a look at the Python version that's being used. It seems that an outdated version of Python is being used (<2.6.3). You might need to install a newer version of Python.